# IE 7: border doesn't work as intended

Tags: html, css

I've defined a html table and I need css works both in IE 9 and IE 7 (with or without hacks). My css is described below:

```
.grid
{
border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
background-color: #D5E0FF;
color: #555555;
font-size: 11px;
border-collapse: collapse;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-top: -5px;
}

.grid td
{
border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
*padding: 6px 5px 6px;

}

.grid_center_align
{
text-align: center;
}

.grid_data_lotes
{
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
}

.grid_header
{
background-color: #02325E;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

.grid_header a
{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

.grid_header a:hover
{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.grid_header th
{
border: 1px solid #111111;
}
```

The class ".grid_header th" doesn't work well in IE 7, only the border-left on THEAD appears with the defined color. Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The header code:

```
 <thead>
     <tr class="grid_header">
         <th scope="col">
             <a>Name</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
             <a>Status</a>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
        </th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: Don't see that the CSS has any problems that jump out. (Except that the `<a>`s look the same as the rest of the text.) Can you show some html as well?

Comment: I've updated the code with html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 is not very good with `border-spacing`. It needs special care.

In this specific example, it works as expected if you remove the `border` attribute from the table, only leaving the `border` on the `th`. Does that work for you?